# Visual Studio xamarin forms iOS entrypointnotfound with simulator but not iphone

Tags: visual-studio, cross-platform, xamarin.forms, entrypointnotfoundexcept

In my Visual Studio Xamarin Forms iOS project, I am linking against a native (c++) library I built and deployed using Visual Studio Cross C++ Platform. I can link and run against an actual device (through the Mac Server), but I cannot get it to work through the simulator. If I build with the same link settings, the build fails, not being able to find the entrypoint. If I choose not to link, then the build succeeds but I get am Entrypointnotfoundexception when running at the point where I try to call into the native code.

Comment: Is there any way you can upload a sample?

Comment: I get it following the steps and code from this blog:
http://kerry.lothrop.de/c-libraries/
But I also get it on more complex solutions which I've written from scratch.

Comment: Was this solution helpful in investigating the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the [example](https://kerry.lothrop.de/c-libraries/) from your comment, using his sample code [here](https://github.com/lothrop/XamarinNative). I had to do a couple things to get it to run correctly. My problem was on Xamarin.iOS, but the same steps can be applied for Xamarin.Forms, assuming you already have platform-specific integration working.

Since you have the code working on a physical device, you should already have a `Native Static Reference` to your `.a` library. But the iOS simulator runs on the `x86_64` architecture (iOS 11 and later [does not support `i386`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/32-and-64/)), while your device likely runs on some version/variant of `ARM`. It sounds like your library is built to support only your device's architecture. You can check this by running `lipo` from your Mac:

`% lipo -info /usr/lib/libCLib.iOS.a`

To support the sim's architecture as well (see [this article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/)), build the C++ project to the architectures you need to support, then combine them, like so:

`lipo -create -output libCLib.iOS.a libCLib.iOS-x8664.a libCLib.iOS-arm64.a`

Use that output `.a` file as your new `Native Static Reference` file back in Visual Studio. Change `Supported Architectures` in your project settings to `x86_64`, and that should be everything. Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: One more note, though possibly obvious: if you need to use the C++ compiler, you will need to add `-cxx` to the "Additional mtouch arguments" in the **iOS Build** tab of your Project settings.

Comment: In addition to the above for the Simulator, my mtouch arguments for the iPhone were `-cxx -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -all_load"`.