# Steps for linking static C/C++ library for iOS in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios

From Xamarin docs at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/, it appears the following flags must be specified for the main iOS project:

```
-cxx -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lMylibrary -lSystemLibrary
-framework CFNetwork -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libMyLibrary.a"
```

However, this article is a bit dated. Is the process still the same for Visual Studio 2015? Where exactly do I specify these flags? Does it go in Project --> Properties --> iOS Build --> Additional mtouch arguments?

Also, Visual Studio has a standard output directory for each project in a solution. How does my library file get copied to $(ProjectDir)? Regards.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it go in Project --> Properties --> iOS Build --> Additional
>   mtouch arguments?

Yep. I found [this](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=man%3amtouch(1)) link to be somewhat helpful when considering what's available to me.

> How does my library file get copied to $(ProjectDir)?

Assuming you are already [connected to your Macbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/), when you build the Xamarin Agent copies your files into a cache directory on the Mac. For me, this was here:

`/Users/myname/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/` (hidden)

You will need to include your libraries in your project, which I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48893719/1964319) as a `Native Static Reference`. This was simpler for me than using a [Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/). However you do it, once your libraries are included in the iOS project, they will be copied into that cache directory on build. Note that they might be in a subdirectory of that cache, requiring you to modify your `${ProjectDir}/libMyLibrary.a` argument in `gcc_flags`.

I know this is an old question, but I hope somebody can get some use from it.